# Number of clubs in a cardinal

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

How can  I compute the number of clubs (closed unbounded subsets) of a cardinal $\kappa$? I feel like there should $\kappa$ many of them but I am a bit lost about how to prove it...

Comment: Try $2^{\kappa}$

Comment: Building $\kappa$ many normal functions and considering their images?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $$\kappa=L\cup S$$ where $L$ is the set of limit ordinals, and $S$  of successor ordinals. Then for eaxh $X\subseteq S$, $$L\cup X$$ is a club.

Comment: Hum ok seems so easy once you see the solution... Thank you!

Comment: I was going to answer but this answer is too simple to be improved upon.